# Создать структуру SYSTEM_INFO на ассемблере

Tags: winapi, ассемблер

Нужно создать структуру http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724958

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_INFO {
  union {
    DWORD  dwOemId;
    struct {
      WORD wProcessorArchitecture;
      WORD wReserved;
    };
  };
  DWORD     dwPageSize;
  LPVOID    lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
  LPVOID    lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
  DWORD_PTR dwActiveProcessorMask;
  DWORD     dwNumberOfProcessors;
  DWORD     dwProcessorType;
  DWORD     dwAllocationGranularity;
  WORD      wProcessorLevel;
  WORD      wProcessorRevision;
} SYSTEM_INFO;
```

Чтобы потом заполнить её ф-ей: GetSystemInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

какая реализация нужна: masm, fasm, tasm?
Реализация под fasm:

```
struct SYSTEMINFO
   union
    dwOemId                     dd ?
    struct 
       wProcessorArchitecture      dw ?
       wReserved                   dw ?
    ends
   ends

   dwPageSize                  dd ?
   lpMinimumApplicationAddress dd ?
   lpMaximumApplicationAddress dd ?
   dwActiveProcessorMask       dd ?
   dwNumberOfProcessors        dd ?
   dwProcessorType             dd ?
   dwAllocationGranularity     dd ?
   wProcessorLevel             dw ?
   wProcessorRevision          dw ?
 ends
```